# Can't see the history of an account that paid me

Tags: horizon, accounts, payments

One of the accounts on my platform received a payment on **15/07/18**  from [THIS ACCOUNT](https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/account/GDOLK4DPTG32FMBNZY7KQXVRJWJMWOZS7ILO7UKEEKQTJ7KRBMFB6AUN?ts=2018-07-15) but I can't retrieve the history of the sender account from any explorer.

Here is the screenshot of payments from my account's history:
[image]

Is there any way to find out the history of an account by his public key?

Comment: the account is not exist GDOLK4DPTG32FMBNZY7KQXVRJWJMWOZS7ILO7UKEEKQTJ7KRBMFB6AUN

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the payments by account endpoint of Horizon we can see that the from account has since been merged into `GCXELXZUHZEZFT5E63P2R2HMXJ3MPPIVR3TI2MDBP244ECRBQEFBVKCG`.

```
  {
    "_links": {
      "self": {
        "href": "https://horizon.stellar.org/operations/81346985528979457"
      },
      "transaction": {
        "href": "https://horizon.stellar.org/transactions/03afaa1946bc31043ff69b362198dfab2c838bb3b14a9f7f56a7ca209201a00e"
      },
      "effects": {
        "href": "https://horizon.stellar.org/operations/81346985528979457/effects"
      },
      "succeeds": {
        "href": "https://horizon.stellar.org/effects?order=desc\u0026cursor=81346985528979457"
      },
      "precedes": {
        "href": "https://horizon.stellar.org/effects?order=asc\u0026cursor=81346985528979457"
      }
    },
    "id": "81346985528979457",
    "paging_token": "81346985528979457",
    "source_account": "GDOLK4DPTG32FMBNZY7KQXVRJWJMWOZS7ILO7UKEEKQTJ7KRBMFB6AUN",
    "type": "account_merge",
    "type_i": 8,
    "created_at": "2018-07-15T16:51:38Z",
    "transaction_hash": "03afaa1946bc31043ff69b362198dfab2c838bb3b14a9f7f56a7ca209201a00e",
    "account": "GDOLK4DPTG32FMBNZY7KQXVRJWJMWOZS7ILO7UKEEKQTJ7KRBMFB6AUN",
    "into": "GCXELXZUHZEZFT5E63P2R2HMXJ3MPPIVR3TI2MDBP244ECRBQEFBVKCG"
  }
```

Your transaction occurred within the previous 200 payments from this account, so we can see it in this document:

```
curl -s "https://horizon.stellar.org/accounts/GDOLK4DPTG32FMBNZY7KQXVRJWJMWOZS7ILO7UKEEKQTJ7KRBMFB6AUN/payments?limit=200&order=desc" | jq '._embedded.records[]|select(.to=="GCLRSKEVESJZKAO5RTLULY3SS5V4F42XB6S4V4VTPRANDQDRMK7RFEBT")'
{
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "https://horizon.stellar.org/operations/81314549935923201"
    },
    "transaction": {
      "href": "https://horizon.stellar.org/transactions/e49b45673b3e6aacabdf02c6039ed9ffa513480d2c799bee185831e60a1091a7"
    },
    "effects": {
      "href": "https://horizon.stellar.org/operations/81314549935923201/effects"
    },
    "succeeds": {
      "href": "https://horizon.stellar.org/effects?order=desc&cursor=81314549935923201"
    },
    "precedes": {
      "href": "https://horizon.stellar.org/effects?order=asc&cursor=81314549935923201"
    }
  },
  "id": "81314549935923201",
  "paging_token": "81314549935923201",
  "source_account": "GDOLK4DPTG32FMBNZY7KQXVRJWJMWOZS7ILO7UKEEKQTJ7KRBMFB6AUN",
  "type": "payment",
  "type_i": 1,
  "created_at": "2018-07-15T06:21:46Z",
  "transaction_hash": "e49b45673b3e6aacabdf02c6039ed9ffa513480d2c799bee185831e60a1091a7",
  "asset_type": "native",
  "from": "GDOLK4DPTG32FMBNZY7KQXVRJWJMWOZS7ILO7UKEEKQTJ7KRBMFB6AUN",
  "to": "GCLRSKEVESJZKAO5RTLULY3SS5V4F42XB6S4V4VTPRANDQDRMK7RFEBT",
  "amount": "0.0000805"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [payments for account API](https://horizon.stellar.org/accounts/GDOLK4DPTG32FMBNZY7KQXVRJWJMWOZS7ILO7UKEEKQTJ7KRBMFB6AUN/payments) to see the [payments for that account](https://horizon.stellar.org/accounts/GDOLK4DPTG32FMBNZY7KQXVRJWJMWOZS7ILO7UKEEKQTJ7KRBMFB6AUN/payments) even though the account itself has been merged and no longer exists.